# Can't get output reversed reading from a file C

Tags: c, arrays, reverse

I want to do something pretty simple, but somehow it doesn't do what I want.
I have a file with numbers in it. I wanna read from that file and print those numbers but in reverse order.

so let's say we have the numers:
10
32
43
6
7
I want to have:
7
6
43
32
10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 255

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char userInput[MAX], target[MAX];

    FILE *file = stdin;
    if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s[<file>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (argc == 2) {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!file) {
            perror(argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    while(fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), file)) {

        size_t len = strlen(userInput);


        int i;
        for (i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (userInput[i] == ' ') {


                userInput[i] = '\0';


                printf("%s ", &(userInput[i]) + 1);
            }
        }


        printf("%s", userInput);


    }
    if (file != stdin) {
        fclose(file);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Does anyone see the mistake?

This is the content of my .txt file:

```
11
34
45
3
78
43
3
4
9
34
23
43
```

Comment: can you add your input file content to the question?

Comment: added see above

Answer (score 1):

Your program is designed to accept all of its input on a single line. Your input file contains multiple lines.

Comment: But using fgets should read multiple lines. Don't see the problem.

Comment: `fgets()` breaks at new line character and the numbers in your file are all on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

The following 1. solution is based on the example shown in the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 255

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char userInput[MAX] = "";
    char target[MAX] = "";
    FILE *file = stdin;

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s[<file>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!file)
        {
            perror(argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* Read all numbers from file and write it to target buffer */
    while(fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), file))
    {
        /* Break loop if there is not enough space to store current number. */
        if ((strlen(target) + strlen(userInput)) >= MAX)
        {
            break;
        }

        /* Add current number read from file to target buffer */
        strcat(target, userInput);
        /* Print current number read from file */
        printf("%s", userInput);
    }
    if (file != stdin) {
        fclose(file);
    }

    /*
     * Run over target buffer in reverse order and replace current number
     * split character '\n' by string end marker '\0'.
     * After that print current number.
     */
    size_t len = strlen(target);

    if (len > 0)
    {
        for (size_t i = len-1; i != 0; i--)
        {
            if (target[i] == '\n')
            {
                target[i] = '\0';
                printf("%s\n", &(target[i]) + 1);
            }
        }

        /* Print first number */
        printf("%s\n", &(target[0]));
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

However it might be better to store the numbers within an array of integer using `sscanf()` and after that print the content of the array in reverse order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 255

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char userInput[MAX] = "";
    int nums[MAX];
    int count = 0;
    FILE *file = stdin;

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s[<file>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!file)
        {
            perror(argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* Read all numbers from file and write it to target buffer */
    while(fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), file))
    {
        sscanf(userInput, "%i", &nums[count]);
        /* Break loop if there is not enough space to store current number. */
        if (count >= MAX)
        {
            break;
        }
        count++;

        /* Print current number read from file */
        printf("%s", userInput);
    }
    if (file != stdin) {
        fclose(file);
    }

    /* Print numbers stored in array in reverse order */
    printf("\n");
    for (int idx = count; idx != 0; idx--)
    {
        printf("%i\n", nums[idx-1]);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I never used sscanf. It is used for formatted reading...is it essential here? Maybe you can shortly explain why you use it.

Comment: I just wanted to show a second solution using `sscanf()`. However it's important to tell that my solutions require that each number is on a separate line. The original example requires one input line and number separation by space character.

Answer (score 1):

You can read your input file starting from the end using `fseek`

Here there's a possible implementation based on your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 255

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i = 0, end = 0, cnt = 0;
    char ch, cnt_flag = 0;
    char userInput[MAX];

    FILE *fp = stdin;
    if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s[<fp>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (argc == 2) {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!fp) {
            perror(argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    end = ftell(fp);

    while (i < end) {
        i++;
        fseek(fp, -i, SEEK_END);
        ch = fgetc(fp);

        if (cnt_flag == 1) {
            cnt++;
            if (ch == '\n') {
                /* skip empty lines */
                if (cnt > 1) {
                    fgets(userInput, cnt, fp);
                    printf("%s\n", userInput);
                }
                cnt_flag = 0;
                cnt = 0;
            }

        }
        if (ch == '\n')
            cnt_flag = 1;
    }

    /* read first line */
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fgets(userInput, cnt + 1, fp);
    printf("%s\n", userInput);

    if (fp != stdin) {
        fclose(fp);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If u need to reverse strings in **file**, check this out. This is **crossplatform** solution without big chunk buffer usage. Only restriction that this is for **file operations only**. Advantages: file size independent solution.

This example based on your code.

```
#ifdef _WIN32 
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define NEW_LINE 2  // Windows new line: 2 bytes (CR) + (LF)
#else 
#define NEW_LINE 1  // Linux new line: 1 byte (LF)
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 255

// This function can be replaced with any other solution 
// u need (write data into another file, or allocate data in the memory and etc)
void printLineFromFile(FILE *file) {
    char buff[255];
    // write line with \n to buff
    fgets(buff, 255, file);
    // total buff size
    int buffLen = strlen(buff);
    int printLen = buffLen;
    // printLen equals buffLen if the last symbol isn't \n
    if (buff[buffLen - 1] == '\n') printLen--;
    // print specified amount of bytes from buff
    fprintf(stdout, "%.*s\n", printLen, buff);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *file = stdin;
    if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s[<file>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (argc == 2) {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!file) {
            perror(argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // set position to the end of file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

    // endPosition - position of last byte in file. (not EOF)
    long endPosition = ftell(file) - 1;

    // currPosition - moving position across the file
    long currPosition = endPosition;

    // byte buffer to read into it
    int ch;

    while (currPosition >= 0) {

        // moving file position to the currPosition
        fseek(file, currPosition, SEEK_SET);

        if (currPosition == 0) {
            printLineFromFile(file);
            currPosition -= NEW_LINE;
            continue;
        }
        ch = fgetc(file);
        if (ch == '\n') {
            if (currPosition == endPosition) {
                currPosition -= NEW_LINE;
                fprintf(stdout, "\n");
            }
            else {
                printLineFromFile(file);
                currPosition -= NEW_LINE;
                continue;
            }
        }
        // move back to position before fgetc
        currPosition--;
    };

    if (file != stdin) {
        fclose(file);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```